# Busca contando resultado

Tags: php, mysql

Faço uma busca por um determinado termo e mostro o resultado, o que está correto, agora preciso mostrar a quantidade de cada produto por categoria, por exemplo, pesquisa pelo termo "cadeira".

```
COZINHA (10)
DORMITÓRIO (05)
```

A minha busca pelo termo ficou assim:

```
mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);
$query_rsBusca = "SELECT marca.descricao AS marca, 
                         produtos.id_produto, 
                         produtos.id_departamento,
                         produtos.id_subdepartamento,
                         produtos.id_marca, 
                         produtos.descricao AS prodDesc, 
                         produtos.codigo_msb 
                    FROM produtos INNER JOIN marca ON (produtos.id_marca = marca.id_marca) 
                   WHERE (produtos.descricao LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%')  OR 
                         (produtos.resumo LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%')     OR 
                         (produtos.codigo_msb LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%') OR 
                         (produtos.detalhes LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%')   OR 
                         (marca.descricao LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%') $ordena ";
// echo $query_rsBusca;
$rsBusca = mysql_query($query_rsBusca, $conexao) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsBusca = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsBusca);
$totalRows_rsBusca = mysql_num_rows($rsBusca);
```

Em seguida fiz um novo conjunto de registro para mostrar as categorias e seus valores, ficou assim:

```
mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);
$query_rsSoma = "SELECT 
                      departamento.descricao AS descricao,
                      COUNT(*) AS Registros
                    FROM
                      departamento 
                      INNER JOIN produtos ON (produtos.id_departamento = departamento.id_departamento)
                      INNER JOIN marca ON (produtos.id_marca = marca.id_marca)
                    WHERE
                      (produtos.descricao LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%')  OR 
                      (produtos.resumo LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%')     OR 
                      (produtos.codigo_msb LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%') OR 
                      (produtos.detalhes LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%')   OR 
                      (marca.descricao LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%'))
                    GROUP BY
                      departamento.id_departamento";
$rsSoma = mysql_query($query_rsSoma, $conexao) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsSoma = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsSoma);
$totalRows_rsSoma = mysql_num_rows($rsSoma);
```

Mas ao executar a *query*, meu servidor acusa o seguinte erro:

> ```
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> ```
>
> near ') GROUP BY departamento.id_departamento' at line 13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o meu problema, estava sobrando um ")" no final do comando, vejam como ficou a Query completa corrigida.

```
mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);
$query_rsBusca = "SELECT marca.descricao AS marca, 
                         produtos.id_produto, 
                         produtos.id_departamento,
                         produtos.id_subdepartamento,
                         produtos.id_marca, 
                         produtos.descricao AS prodDesc, 
                         produtos.codigo_msb 
                    FROM produtos INNER JOIN marca ON (produtos.id_marca = marca.id_marca) 
                   WHERE (produtos.descricao LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%')  OR 
                         (produtos.resumo LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%')     OR 
                         (produtos.codigo_msb LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%') OR 
                         (produtos.detalhes LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%')   OR 
                         (marca.descricao LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%') $ordena ";
// echo $query_rsBusca;
$rsBusca = mysql_query($query_rsBusca, $conexao) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsBusca = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsBusca);
$totalRows_rsBusca = mysql_num_rows($rsBusca);

mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);
$query_rsSoma = "SELECT 
                      departamento.descricao AS descricao,
                      COUNT(*) AS Registros
                    FROM
                      departamento 
                      INNER JOIN produtos ON (produtos.id_departamento = departamento.id_departamento)
                      INNER JOIN marca ON (produtos.id_marca = marca.id_marca)
                    WHERE
                      (produtos.descricao LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%')  OR 
                      (produtos.resumo LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%')     OR 
                      (produtos.codigo_msb LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%') OR 
                      (produtos.detalhes LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%')   OR 
                      /* AQUI TINHA UM ')' A MAIS */ 
                      (marca.descricao LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%')
                    GROUP BY
                      departamento.id_departamento";
$rsSoma = mysql_query($query_rsSoma, $conexao) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsSoma = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsSoma);
$totalRows_rsSoma = mysql_num_rows($rsSoma);
```

Obrigado a ajuda e as dicas.